# Git merge doesn't report submodule changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project with 2 branches called master and production. These 2 branches have a dependency included in the submodule plugin1. In master plugin1 points to the latest revision (rev2),  whereas the production branch points to the previous commit (rev1).

When I merge master into production, I expect to have a production branch that now points to the revision rev2, but it doesn't. Is there an option to do that, or do I have to manually report the changes in the production branch?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a merge in git that results in a submodule changing version, it won't automatically check out that new version in the submodule.  I suspect that if you do:

```
git status
```

... it will report that the submodule is at the wrong version.  If so, you can update it with:

```
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a post merge hook that will ask you, something like [this](https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils).

Keep in mind that `git submodule update` can ***remove your local committed but not pushed changes*** if you have any:
Quoting from [git manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#submodules):

> It’s not safe to run git submodule update if you’ve made and committed
>   changes within a submodule without checking out a branch first. They
>   will be silently overwritten:
>   (...followed by an example)

HTH